# Exception during quick push for TDS projects

Tags: tds

I am trying to push the items from my TDS project through quick push but I am getting following error.

```
Exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (NullReferenceException):
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.QuickPush.<PushItems>b__0(QuickPushDeployItem i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.QuickPush.PushItems(SitecoreProjectNode project, List`1 itemsToPush)
```

Also I am getting error message that "The quick push process failed with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be related to one of the missing Sitecore items in one of your TDS projects. As per your above error, it is trying to iterate through items in TDS project and found some missing Sitecore items which it is not able to push to Sitecore.

I would suggest that you review your TDS project and see if there are some missing Sitecore items in your TDS project.

Also if you want to find out the missing Sitecore item then try to unload the TDS project and then reload it. You should see output window for Team Development for Sitecore to find the missing Sitecore item.

It should have something like.

The file `'D:\Project\site\tds\Site.Website.Master\sitecore\templates\Project\Site\Content Type\Callouts\CTA\__Standard Values.item'` could not be loaded.

TDS has finished parsing 200 .item files for Site.Website.Master.

Warning: TDS could not load all files for the project. The files may be missing or corrupted. 
Please see the TDS pane in the output window for more details.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I found the missing item. There were certain Sitecore items not checked in by my team member to respository. I got those items and it is working. Thanks again.